# Why is shouldComponentUpdate saying current props are new props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using Redux, but not sure that this would be the cause.

I have code like this

```
<Page>
  <AnotherChild />
  <Pricing quotes={this.props.item.quotes} />
</Page>
```

`<Pricing>` has a child component that fires a dispatch on change of an input, which updates prices of item.

`<Pricing>` has this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  console.log(nextProps.quotes[0].value, this.props.quotes[0].value);
}
```

So let's say the input has `10`, I highlight all and press `5`, the logs show `5` for both the next and current prop values.

Confused how that is the case. I would think I'd need to see a log of 10 -> 5 at some point because it starts at 10 and couldn't magically switch from a parent, right?

**EDIT**

Here is a code block that is triggering the prop change.

```
_updateDiscountAmount() {
  var discountAmount = +this.refs.discount_amount.getValue();

  var quotes = this.props.quotes.map(quote => {

    var promoPrice = quote.value;

    if (Number.isNaN(discountAmount)) {
      discountAmount = 0;
    }

    quote.percentage = discountAmount;

    promoPrice = (promoPrice - (promoPrice * discountAmount/100)).toFixed(2);

    return quote;
  });


  this.props.dispatch({
    type: 'CURRENT_PAGE_UPDATE',
    data: {
      discount_amount: discountAmount,
      quotes
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: Can you producing a working example of this, such as in [codepen](http://codepen.io/)? This is not normal behavior

Comment: @Tyrsius about to pop out of office and this would take some work cause this example is in a bit of a complex app. I am wondering if something is wrong cause some data is nested so far it doesn't get called for that, but something else and I see console.log by coincidence after the fact

Comment: but i guess i should note i don't see any other console logs in render that would indicate it's getting hit multiple times from something not as deeply nested

Comment: There's really not enough to go off here, but...why is `prices` an array? The first element is always what changes? Might be better to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(nextProps.prices), JSON.stringify(this.props.prices))` as a test

Comment: Here is a [minimal demo](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/VaENqg?editors=0010) showing that React normally behaves the way you expect it to. The explanation for the behavior you are seeing must lie elsewhere. We cannot help you without more code.

Comment: Can't deduce that from your code, but typically this happens if your props are not fully immutable. E.g. if `this.props.prices` point to a `prices` object, and some `foo.prices` points to the same object. If you then update `foo.prices[0].value`, you inadvertently also mutate `props`.

Comment: @wintvelt I'm guessing your comment is the reason. I'll be able to check it out and better update question tomorrow at work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@wintvelt above gave the answer so if he writes it in, I will mark it.

Basically the above code is failing. Even though I am mapping to a new array, I am changing what should be unmutable.

All I needed to do to fix the problem was make a copy of `quote` within the loop before modifying it.

ie:

```
var quotes = this.props.quotes.map(quote => {

  // Copy the object here
  quote = Object.assign({}, quote);

  var promoPrice = quote.value;

  if (Number.isNaN(discountAmount)) {
    discountAmount = 0;
  }

  quote.percentage = discountAmount;

  promoPrice = (promoPrice - (promoPrice * discountAmount/100)).toFixed(2);

  return quote;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When your `nextProps` appear to be the same as `this.props`, then usually you somewhere mutate props unintentionally. In an example:

```
// this.props.quotes = [ { discount : 5 }, { discount : 3}];
var quote = this.props.quotes[0];
console.log(quote.discount);               // 5
quote.discount = 10;                       // (!) this also updates props
console.log(this.props.quotes[0].discount); // 10
```

To fix, make a copy of the object before you update, like so:

```
var newQuotes = this.props.quotes.map(quote => {

  // Copy object
  var newQuote = Object.assign({}, quote);
  ...
  newQuote.percentage = discountAmount;
  ...
  return newQuote;
});
```